# Отсортировать массив, состоящий из объектов

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка

Задача состоит в том, чтобы объект с типом документа **pdf** шел на 1-ом месте. Для этого необходимо отсортировать текущую структуру данных. Пробовал через `Object.values` и `reduce` собирать это все, но не вышло:( **P.S.**  1)Можно использовать *Lodash*
2) Лучше без `for in`

```js
const documents = {
  doc1: [{type: 'txt'}, {type: 'pdf'}], //Ожид. рез: [{type: 'pdf'}, {type: 'txt'}]
  doc2: [{type: 'pdf'}, {type: 'txt'}, {type: 'pdf'}]//Ожид. рез: [{type: 'pdf'}, {type: 'pdf'}, {type: 'txt'}]
}
```

Comment: Для сортировки есть метод sort у массивов

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Object.keys(documents).forEach(key => {
  documents[key].sort((a, b) => a.type.localeCompare(b.type))
})
```

например вот так. Метод `sort` мутирующий, поэтому получается не слишком "чисто". Но, в целом, запрошенное делает
Так же, советую явно прописать условия сортировки в зависимости от типа. Я воспользовался тем, что в алфавитном порядке pdf идет раньше txt, но это тоже неявная хитрость.

Comment: Как вариант, я думаю можно использовать deepCopy из лодаша, чтобы не мутировать объект или Json.stringify.
Спасибо за решение!